# Function call as column name

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have SQL Server Management Studio automatically generate column names when none is specified? For instance based on the expression generating them.

For instance, it would be nice to have the query

```
SELECT ProductType, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductType
```

generate something like

```
ProductType | AVG(Price)
------------+-----------
Product1    | 42
...         | ...
```

rather than

```
ProductType | (No column name)
------------+-----------------
Product1    | 42
...         | ...
```

as it currently does.

Comment: Why can't `SELECT ProductType, AVG(Price) as [AVG(Price)]..........` ??

Comment: No, you need to type out the alias.

Comment: I think Oracle's doing it by default. In SQL-Server you need to use alias `AS` . But why in hell do you want this ?

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, this answers my quesiton precisely. If you make it an answer, I'll mark it as correct. :)

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the expression exceeds the 128 character limit for identifiers? This looks like more of a product suggestion than a question. Consider suggesting on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver.

Comment: @sagi Thanks for your reply. Well, I would like to do this, in order to avoid writing names, where just as meaningful names could automatically be generated. It would be nice when exploring data, and running several small queries that don't need to look good, but where it just needs to be possible to reason about the output (what each column means). This is similar to how R handles unnamed parameters: `plot(seq(1,10), seq(11,20))` produces a plot with `x` and `y` labels `seq(1,10)` and `seq(11,20)`, respectivaly. Massively useful!

Comment: @DanGuzman well, that depends on implementation. An error could occur? I don't know, but I guess a reasonably solution could be found. Given that this is not possible, I agree this is better suited as a product suggestion. But I wanted to make sure the feature didn't exist already. Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server (Transact-SQL) ALIASES can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.

```
SELECT ProductType, AVG(Price) as AVG
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductType
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php

Answer (score 0):

You can name a new column in '' too. For example you can write:

```
SELECT ProductType, AVG(Price) as 'AVG(Price)'
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductType
```